Is it possible for a Flink job to be executed without a sink?
I'm trying to cut down the processing time of one of my flink jobs and came to discover that some operators are being executed no matter if they are or not connected to any sinks. Is that even possible? What am I missing here?
The execution plan is in this gist, and there are no sinks in it. Still, my job runs and processes millions of records.
I removed all my sinks and was expecting the program to fail at startup but it didn't. Is it possible that sources push data into the pipeline even without a sink? any clues?
Thank you
